# How to change TextSize and Background Color of a spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-background

I want to change my spinner background color and text size of each item in the Spinner, i already have gone through few answers for questions similar to mine but did not get the answer weather we can change the textSize / Background Color of a spinner or not?   If anyone have a simple answer, i will be thankful to their reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `strings.xml` file create a `<string-array name="spinner">` tag.
create `<item>` tags inside with each entry.
Wrap the text in each `item` with `<![CDATA[ ...raw html... ]]>` tag. Put in the formatting information in the raw html part ofcourse.

In the activity,

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Check the top answer from this post :

[Set TextView text from html-formatted string resource in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml)

Though this refers to a `TextView`, it can be modified to be used in a `Spinner` too.

Comment: may i know, where you changed Color and Size ?

Comment: <![CDATA[... inside here, use raw html to change size, color...]]>

Take a look at the answer in this post:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml)
Click the link.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely what i want, Thank you for you help @Samrat Dutta  . AND after solving this my application encountered another problem i.e its getting force closed when i change my phones landscape mode from vertical to horizontal or vice-versa. i am using just a EditText component with attributes, android:width="fill_parent & android:height="fill_parent"  Do you have any idea over my problem. If you have ay Idea please share here Thank you

Comment: First of all, you always use match_parent instead of fill_parent. Latest convention. But that is not causing the problem. Although you should use layout_weight="1" instead of android:height="fill_parent". Anyway, I need the Logcat error message when the application crashes to try and solve the issue.

Comment: Why dont you post your problem as a separate question with the relevant code that you have tried?

Comment: Because we can post another question only after 90 mins gap

Comment: Please tell me the logcat error. That will help me understand the problem.

Comment: 07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): Process: com.ex.trail, PID: 11780
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at com.ex.trail.BibleActivity.onItemSelected(BibleActivity.java:42)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:964)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:947)

Comment: 07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1114)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1094)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:180)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:503)
07-19 00:26:31.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11780):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17495)

Comment: It is a nullpointer Exception. The Activity cant find the EditText by id when rotated. It is very hard to answer without the code. If and when possible, do post a question with the code. Try putting `if(savedInstanceState != null) {
return;
}`
inside the `onCreate()` method after `setContentView();`

Comment: Thank you, You are Genius @Samrat Dutta

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a custom xml list item for your spinner, something like this `list_item_spinner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#000000"  
    android:textColor="#FB26A9"         
    android:padding="10dip"/>
```

After that use that file in your code as follows

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_spinner, mListData);
```

Comment: But i dont want to change color and size in TextView, i want same in Spinner

Comment: He wants each of his list items to have a different size and background.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Samrat Dutta , If you have appropriate answer please forward it

Comment: I've already posted my solution below. If you have any confusion with it, feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858294/android-each-item-of-spinner-different-color and